# failed to start postgresql on CentOS

Tags: postgresql, centos

start command:

```sh
pg_ctl -D /data/pgsql -l logfile start
```

logfile print following message:

```
could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Address already in use
Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry
```

I try to execute `lsof -i :5432`, but the result is empty.

Comment: Are you running the lsof as root?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yes. There don't have any process to use the port.

Comment: Do you have "listen_addresses" in your configuration?  What version of PostgreSQL?  Does "ifconfig" show the loopback connector with inet 127.0.0.1?